# How to use .svg figures in Latex (Overleaf) using subfolders?

Tags: overleaf

Is there a minimal working example of using `.svg` figures in Overleaf with a project structured in folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a minimally working example of using `.svg` figures in Overleaf, with a folder structure.

Directory structure:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[svgpath=../imgs/]{svg} % <- also works
\usepackage{svg}
\svgpath{{../imgs/}} % <- using \svgpath to avoid warning
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Inkscape package on Overleaf }
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width = 100pt]{image}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

MWE (with some comments): https://www.overleaf.com/read/bvnpfzbpvvmc

*ps: I know there are many similar answers, but none made clear how to use folders and this literally took me 2 hours to figure out, so I'm posting here.*

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the `inkscapelatex=false` argument solved another problem of mine! It prevents the text from being recompiled (not sure if this is correct terminology!) and keeps the text integrity in electronic svg schematics! Thank you.

Comment: @BenFM glad it helped!