How can I setup the TextStudio environment to include non-Inkscape SVG images?
I am trying to get SVG images in my LaTex document but the existing setup doesn't work. I am using TexStudio.
These SVG images are from Adobe Illustrator and MATLAB and I am wondering what's going wrong.
I am including the package in my setup using the command\userpackage{svg} and the compiling is done using the command pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex. Also, the default compiler is set to PdfLatex.
This is an example of how I am including the SVG image
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \hspace{1cm}
    \includesvg{pulse_convection_reflection_tam/test}
    \caption{Illustration for tracing a refracted ray in layer $\ell$.}
    \label{fig:snell_estimations:ray_tracing:rayy_tracing_generalized}
\end{figure}

The error thrown on compiling is
Package svg Error: File `test_svg-tex.pdf' is missing. ...dth]{pulse_convection_reflection_tam/test}

Is there any other package that I need to include to handle the svg to pdf conversion ?

do you have inkscape installed? but can you not simply write pdf from matlab and illustrator? why write svg that needs to be converted to pdf?

Behind the scenes, the svg package will just use inkscape to convert the svg into a pdf+tex file. If this does not work for you, you could just manually convert the svg into a pdf and use \includegraphics to include it in your document.

@DavidCarlisle, I have not tried that. Would it have any scaling issues ? Sam, I am installing Inkscape and will check if this solves the problem. Hoping it does.

it is much better to generate the pdf if possible. svg can not be included in pdf so you have to convert the svg to pdf, making pdf directly is almost always better if you can

None of the options related to Inkscape work. Even when I specify the executable path. What would be right approach to include the pdf images ?

make a pdf in say matlab and include it with \includegraphics no shell escape or contrib packages are needed it should just work.

If you still want to use the svg and Inkscape is properly installed and can be found by LaTeX (and you use -shell-escape which is required for calling Inkscape) then you probably also need to set \svgpath (or as an option in \includesvg) because your svg is in a different folder (or of course put your svg in the main folder to avoid issues). Some more information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527565/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300471/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591213/.
